# How to export query results from a table to csv?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

So I have several pages that query our DB and then present the results in a large table on the webpage. There is also a button that allows the user to export the results to a csv file. This first code snippet works perfectly well. But a couple of the other pages do not work and open a csv file with nothing in it. I got it working briefly last week, but then it stopped working again. When I got it working it appeared to be a formatting inconsistency, which explains why it would work on one page and not another. Also due to this, I do not believe the problem exists in the js that exports it

So here is the working snippet:

```
</div></td>
<td ><div id="layer2">
<p class="bodytext">

<?php

   //select the table
   $query = "SELECT * FROM CEP_T ORDER BY Cep_ID, Student_ID";

   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $numberOfCeps = mysql_numrows($result);

?>

   <html>
   <head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScripts.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="tableSort.js"></script>
   <title>Display CEPs Info...</title>
   <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="formatStyles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen,print>
   </head>

   <body>
   <h3>Display <?php echo $numberOfCeps; ?> CEP designees:</h3>
   <div style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial;"><small><big><big>
   <!-- <span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><a href="reports.php">Back To Reports!</a> </span> -->
<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
<input type="submit" value="Get CSV File" 
        onclick="getCSVData()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javaExport.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCSVData(){
 var csv_value=$('#displayAllCeps').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
 $("#csv_text").val(csv_value); 
}
</script>

<div style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial;"><small><big>

   <?php (then it goes on to define the headers and place the results in table cells)
```

And here is the code that is not working:

```
 </div></td>
<td><div id="layer2">
<p class="bodytext">

<?php
    $contactType = $_GET['contactType'];
    $company = $_GET['company'];
    $endingCreateDate='';
    $beginningCreateDate='';
    $beginningCreateDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['beginningCreateDate']));
    $endingCreateDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['endingCreateDate']));
    $filterwhere="";
    $filterfrom="";
    if($contactType!=""){

    $filterwhere=" AND ct.Contact_Type_ID=$contactType ".$filterwhere;
    //$filterfrom=", CONTACT_T".$filterfrom;
    }
    if($beginningCreateDate!="1969-12-31"){

    $filterwhere=" AND Date_Created > '$beginningCreateDate' ".$filterwhere;
    //$filterfrom=", CONTACT_T".$filterfrom;
    }

    if($endingCreateDate!="1969-12-31"){

    $filterwhere=" AND Date_Created < '$endingCreateDate' ".$filterwhere;
    //$filterfrom=", CONTACT_T".$filterfrom;
    }
    if($company!=""){
            $filterwhere=" AND Individual_Company='$company' ".$filterwhere;
    //$filterfrom=", INDIVIDUAL_WORK_INFO_T".$filterfrom;
    }

        $query = "SELECT i.Individual_ID,First_Name,Last_Name,Email_Address, Address1,Address2,City,State,Postal_Code,Country,Home_Phone,Mobile_Phone,Individual_Company,Work_Phone,Work_Extension,Region,Date_Created, Last_Meeting_Date, Referred_By, c.Note,     ct.Contact_Type, i.Do_Not_Mail
        FROM INDIVIDUAL_T i                
        INNER JOIN CONTACT_T c ON c.Contact_ID=i.Individual_ID
        INNER JOIN INDIVIDUAL_WORK_INFO_T iw ON iw.Individual_ID =i.Individual_ID
        INNER JOIN CONTACT_TYPE_T ct ON c.Contact_Type=Contact_Type_ID".$filterfrom."
        WHERE Is_Student = 'No' AND Is_Contact = 'Yes'".$filterwhere."
        ORDER BY Last_Name, First_Name";

   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $numberOfRows = mysql_numrows($result);
?>

   <html>
   <head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tableSort.js"></script>
   <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="formatStyles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen,print>
   <title>Display all contacts...</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <h3>Display <?php echo $numberOfRows; ?> contacts...</h3>
   <div style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial;"><small><big><big>
   <!-- <span style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><a href="reports.php">Back To Reports!</a> </span> -->

<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
<input type="submit" value="Get CSV File" 
        onclick="getCSVData()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javaExport.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCSVData(){
 var csv_value=$('#displayAllContacts').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
 $("#csv_text").val(csv_value); 
}
</script>
<div style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial;"><small><big>
<!--<div id="Book1_10219" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">-->
<?php(then it goes on to define the headers and place the results in table cells)
```

I apologize for my ignorance, but i have been staring at the code for several days now and have no idea what else to do

Comment: Well, your broken code has some html snippets **BEFORE** the `<html>` tag, which is definitely not a good thing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code http://bit.ly/phpmsql. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation. Learn about Prepared statements http://j.mp/T9hLWi instead, and use PDO http://php.net/pdo or MySQLi http://php.net/mysqli. This article: http://j.mp/QEx8IB will help you decide which.

Comment: Are there any commas, single quotes or other characters in the data that could break CSV? Does your export library have any error reporting or debugging code that you could turn on?

Comment: No need to apologize for ignorance, but then you should know that debugging is better than staring at the code for several days. Approach the problem systematically to allow you to pinpoint the problem. Anyway, @MarcB pointed out the first obvious issue. If not that, display input, display SQL, check results,...

Comment: I know this is a little delayed. Still getting used to etiquite on the site. Anyway, the cause of the problem was that a javascript function was passing the entire contents of the report (by grabbing all content of each row) as a single variable. This worked fine until the report size grew too large. I created php function that calls the queries again and exports the csv. Works great now.